# Стартовый размер em

Tags: html, css

На сайте каким-то образом задан больший размер em, чем у браузера. Есть способ перенастроить данный параметр?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

em берет свою ширину относительно родительского элемента. Например, вы может установить на body размер шрифта 14 пикселей. И тогда 1em у потомков будет равняться 14 пикселям.
Если внутри body вы добавите, например, div с font-size: 0.8em, то потомки этого дива с размером шрифта 1em будут отображеы с размером шрифта 11,2 пикселя.

Существует также единица измерения rem, которая не наследуется от родителя, а наследуется от дефолтного значения (если мне память не изменяет) браузера (обычно это 16px).

Answer (score 2):

Возможно, разница в шрифтах? Быть может на локальном они подгружаются, а на хостинге нет?

Comment: Использую Ариал и хелеврику. Мне кажется, что проблема в том что некоторые параметры считаются в em, например margin: .6em 30% .8em;

Можно как то задать стартовый размер em?

Comment: Я не думаю то что величина отступов (margin) может влиять на размер шрифтов.

Comment: шрифты тоже в em... 

Это Jquery mobile...

Comment: Ну тогда вероятно проблема в этом.

Comment: сделайте reset.css файл, где будут изначально сбрасываться все настройки браузера, так принято.